# Excel Converter Linhas em Colunas

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha com várias linhas desta forma

```
NOME:      | EDSON
SOBRENOME: | CARLOS
TELEFONE:  | 1299232322
NOME:      | TESTE
SOBRENOME: | AMANDEU
TELEFONE:  | 1499252322
NOME:      | JOSE
SOBRENOME: | PASTOR
TELEFONE:  | 1299232322
```

Ou seja, são 2 colunas, uma com o nome do campo e a outra com o valor, como faço para colocar cada um em sua colunas ? desta forma

```
NOME    | SOBRENOME   | TELEFONE
EDSON   | CARLOS      | 1299232322
TESTE   | AMANDEU     | 1499252322
JOSE    | PASTOR      | 1299232322
```

Comment: Quer que isto seja feito de forma automática? com VBA (não sei se é a linguagem correta)? de mais detalhes para que outros membros possam te ajudar

Comment: Pergunta: Os camos são sempre os mesmos e todos os contatos tem todos os campos ou corre o risco de um determinado contato não ter TELEFONE, por exemplo. Pergunto isso, pois existe uma solução bem simples, caso tudo seja padronizado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que é tudo padronizado, ou seja, que todos os contatos possuem todos os campos (NOME,SOBRENOME e TELEFONE), existe uma solução bem simples e rápida.

A minha explicação será baseada na imagem abaixo.

[image: Excel]

A solução se baseia em três colunas auxiliares, são elas D,E,F. A coluna D é para o NOME, a coluna E para SOBRENOME e a coluna F para o TELEFONE.

Essas colunas guardam a linha onde se encontram cada NOME,SOBRENOME e TELEFONE respectivamente.

- Para preencher a coluna D, comece com o numero 1 fixo e depois faça uma fórmula que incrementa o valor da célula anterior com 3. Assim, D2 = 1, D3 = D2 + 3, D4 = D3+3 e assim por diante.
- Faça o mesmo para as colunas E e F, só que a E deve começar de 2 e a F de 3.
- Feito isso, escreva nas colunas G,H e I o nome das colunas.
- Para finalizar, escreva a seguinte fórmula na célula G2: **ÍNDICE($B$1:$B$9;D2)**
- Copie e cole essa fórmula para o restante das colunas.
- Para retirar as fórmulas ÍNDICE, copie o intervalo e Cole Especial (somente os valores).

Comment: Rapaz, perguntei na stack em inglês e ninguém soube responder, achei que era um problema sem solução, como vc mesmo disse, é bem simples porem eu não teria a ideia eu mesmo. Me ajudou muito, obrigado.